# Why is the line alignment off between the first and second column in this table?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, cell

The line alignment between the first column is off. The cells in the first column start a line higher. I use overleaf, and I have tried to make a minimal example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Uncomment the next line to use the natbib package with bibtex 

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl,rotating,booktabs,bigstrut}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pbox}


\begin{document}


\newgeometry{left=0.75cm,right=0.75cm,bottom=2cm}





% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Overview of effects of independent variables}
  \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{p{18.0em}|p{8em}|p{7.00em}|p{7.00em}}
       \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{p{18em}|}{\pbox{7cm}{AP:some text \newline{} D: some text; some text}}  & - Higher age & Increase foregone earnings & \multicolumn{1}{p{7.215em}|}{Increase study effort} 
        \midrule
    \end{tabular}%
    }
    \label{tab:literaturereviewtable}%
\end{table}%
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

And the result I get

[image]

My problem is that the text is not vertically aligned in the across the first column and the others.

I hope one of you great people can help me our.

Best regard

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: your example produces the error `! Misplaced \noalign.` after _any_ error the PDF is not intended to be usable, if asking questions about it you should ask about the error not any pdf that is generated if you scroll past the error.

Comment: okay. First good advice of the day. Thanks. Im very new to the whole Latex thing, so thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the (unnecessary) `\pbox` here which sets the first entry in a tabular, which by default is vertically centred, so the baseline of the later entries align with the centre of the first entry.

The `\multicolumn{1}` are not helping here, just removing them improves things

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Uncomment the next line to use the natbib package with bibtex 

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl,rotating,booktabs,bigstrut}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pbox}


\begin{document}


\newgeometry{left=0.75cm,right=0.75cm,bottom=2cm}





% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Overview of effects of independent variables}
% no please never scale tables   \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{18.0em}|
                    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{8em}|
                    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{7.00em}|
                    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{7.00em}}
       \toprule
      AP:some text \newline D: some text; some text  & - Higher age & Increase foregone earnings & Increase study effort\\
        \midrule
    \end{tabular}%
%    }
    \label{tab:literaturereviewtable}%
\end{table}%
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: note I left them in, but you should not use vertical rules (`|`) with booktabs tables (the package documentation is _very_ explicit that they are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Converting Excel table to LaTeX table by help of some program/plug-inn many times doesn't gives expected result. It seems that is limited in selection of best appropriate table packages for converted table, alo in composing cells where is often used clutter as are `multicolumn{1} ...` , `\parbox` in your converted table.

Yes, typing of table directly in LaTeX is somehow demanding. If it looks very challenging at first, after a few exercises, the skills to write them are quickly acquired. The reward is better designed tables, where the code is clear and mostly much more condensed.

For example, your table can be simple write by use novel table package `tabularray`. Table's code is simple, clear and concise:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Uncomment the next line to use the natbib package with bibtex
%\usepackage{}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow}
%\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl,rotating,bigstrut}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage{pbox}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{left=0.75cm,right=0.75cm,bottom=2cm}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Overview of effects of independent variables}
    \label{tab:literaturereviewtable}
\begin{tblr}{vlines,
             colspec = {X[2.5, l] *{3}{X[1,l]} }
             }
       \toprule
{AP: some text\\
  D: some text; some text}    & - Higher age & Increase foregone earnings 
                            & Increase study effort \\
        \midrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}%
\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

BTW, I wonder, why you need have so wide table. If you will add more realistic (still dummy) content of table, people here may give you additional advices how to write your table. For example, that contents in the second column are lists which can be nicer if for them would be used `\enumitem` package.